# Extract Links from Facebook activity feed

Tags: php, facebook, android-activity, feed, scrape

I'm trying to get the links from a facebook activity feed, i've tried extracting the HTML from the iframe, but this doesn't work because of cross domain. Then I tried cURL but that doesn't work because of the javascript.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/activity

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible, basically it requires your session that you can't maintain in iframe, I tried this some days ago through file_get_contents and cURL but nothing works.

Comment: yeah thats what I thought too :/

Comment: That's why they are champs! The Facebook. I know its frustrating for we developers but its great to maintain user's privacy think if they provide some features for that to developers then a develper can misuse it by getting user's information through cURL or any other method without alerting users.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a javascript library like jQuery to extract all of the links then send the data to a PHP script but that wouldn't work if your trying to automate it.

Your best bet is to use the [Facebook API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) rather than a social plugin.

Comment: Hi thanks for getting back to me, jQuery would be a good solution, however I don't think it would run cross domain??

Comment: Do you know if the Facebook API has a section for an activity feed?