# Subscribe via webhook to a Facebook user's Activity Feed?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'd like to use the GraphAPI and Webhooks to subscribe to a user's activity feed and extract information such as metadata and stats about the shared posts they like. (Yes, I am well aware of the privacy concerns and this will be handled extremely carefully.)

The closest question I could find is here:

- [Extract Links from Facebook activity feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4603733/extract-links-from-facebook-activity-feed)

The other answers are not relevant, as they either discuss the old FQL or plugins or are specific to Pages.

I've been reading the GraphAPI documentation and the [User Likes](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/likes/) information only relates to the Pages they like (which doesn't change much). So this is a subset of the info needed - I need likes for Posts, not just Pages.

What I am really interested in is the objects to which a given user has reacted. You can easily see the reactions for everyone to a given post with a `GET /v2.8/{post-id}/reactions HTTP/1.1` call.  But this is "reactions by post" and I need "reactions by user".

The best solution I can figure out so far is to subscribe to their feed with a webhook and then collect a list of object IDs and then subscribe to their reactions for a certain period and filter by the user.  This is not ideal or very efficient as it requires a fair number of subscriptions, and also only accounts for posts in the user's feed and not other posts they might have stumbled upon via some other means.

So - how to extract *all* User Like info?

Comment: Facebook will not approve your app’s use of the necessary permissions in review anyway, if you plan to use them for analytical purposes only.

Comment: Interesting, I must read the T&Cs for publishing apps.  However, it's actually for much more than analytics. I just don't want to give away the entire concept. The intent is something which has a direct benefit to the user.

Comment: There is no API access to the activity log. If the user likes posts that you don’t get to see via their feed - then you simply won’t know about it.

Comment: Ok, so no activity log access, as I suspected. What about getting all Likes on Posts? (And not just Pages.) TIA...